# Different prediction results on CPU and GPU Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, cudnn

I have trained a model using TF 0.8 (which is the highest TF version I can use on a TK1), and the prediction accuracy on my laptop is ~80%, when I then move the model to the TK1 running Jetson to predict using GPU acceleration, the accuracy is ~55%. I am using the exact same code with the same saved weights file.

Here is my code for loading and predicting the validation data:

```
def load_model_1():
    images, labels = get_data("data.csv", "labels.csv", train=False)
    sess = tf.Session()
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('training1/model.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, 'training1/model.ckpt')
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    eval_preds = graph.get_operation_by_name('eval_prediction').outputs[0]
    valid_preds = []

    for image in images:
        valid_pred = sess.run([eval_preds], feed_dict = {'eval:0': np.array([image])})[0][0]

        valid_preds.append(valid_pred)

    print("Error: ",  predict_accuracy(np.array(valid_preds), labels))
```

Any ideas on why this happens and how to fix it? I don't think it is a memory error, the GPU has ~ 400 MiB of free memory. is there a way to check the memory the model is using?

Comment: gpu prediction should not impact the accuracy